# Prevent a Float from entering a certain area

Tags: floats, positioning, placeins

I really like the \floatbarrier command.
I was wondering if there is a way to prevent a float from entering an area.

```
\floatbarrier
Some Text
Some other Text
\startForbiddenArea %%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{itemize}
\endForbiddenArea %%%%%%%%%%%%
some text
\floatbarrier
```

So that you can for example prevent the float from entering the this itemize.

Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: `\suppressfloats` (which works per page, like `\thispagestyle` not per environment)

Comment: For a small list (less than one page/column) you can use also a  `minipage`  or even a float with `[H]`, that also will avoid page breaks.

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment the first `\floatbarrier` will flush any pending floats so the only way a float could disturb the `itemize` is for a float entered after the fragment shown to float "backwards" to the top of the page, into the list.

You can use `\suppressfloats[t]` to (usually) prevent top floats on the current page, or use the `flfter` package that globally prevents floats moving "backwards" by disallowing `t` position on the page a float is entered.